# Expand UITableViewCell with animation

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uiimageview

I'm trying to implement functionality in my `UITableView` where a `UITableViewCell`'s `UIImageView` expands to fill up the complete view after a user touches the cell.

This is the animation I'm using:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImageView *imageView = [cell viewWithTag:1];
UIView *cellView = [cell viewWithTag:2];

CGRect rectInTableView = [_tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^(void)
                     {
                         imageView.frame = rectInTableView;
                         imageView.tag = 123;
                         [self.navigationController.view addSubview:imageView];
                         [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height+64)];
                         imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
                     }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
                     {}];
```

What happens now, though, is that a `UIImageView` jumps to the top and then expands. I want it to expand from the cell though. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This might accomplish what you're trying to do:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImageView *imageView = [cell viewWithTag:1];
UIView *cellView = [cell viewWithTag:2];

CGRect rectInTableView = [_tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
imageView.frame = rectInTableView;
imageView.tag = 123;
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:imageView];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^(void)
                     {
                         [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height+64)];
                         imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
                     }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
                     {}];
```

Comment: This works like it should, but the `UIImageView` now has the x,y of the cell. I want it to expand to x,y = 0,0